# Merge 2 values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, php-7.3

After previously had exploded the data, there is a portion I need to rebuild/merge again.
period in [category-X] index [1] with its value [2] should be merged and positioned in index [1].

Finally , the rest of index in each category should be moved up one step, since otherwise index [2] would be left blank.

---

**My code:**

```
$array = [
  'category-1' => [
    'data_first',
    'period',
    '0',
    'data_last',
  ],
  'category-2' => [
    'data_first',
    'period',
    '2',
    'data_last',
  ]
];

print_r($array);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [category-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => data_first
            [1] => period
            [2] => 0 // To be merged with period in index [1]
            [3] => data_last
        )

    [category-2] => Array
        (
            [0] => data_first
            [1] => period
            [2] => 2 // To be merged with period in index [1]
            [3] => data_last
        )

)
```

**Wanted Result**

```
 Array
(
    [category-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => data_first
            [1] => period0
            [2] => data_last
        )

    [category-2] => Array
        (
            [0] => data_first
            [1] => period2
            [2] => data_last
        )

)
```

Comment: @Kevin, sure I will try.

Comment: @CBroe Understood, I will update the question.

Comment: here's a guide, use a foreach, use a reference `&`, overwrite the first index with the concatenated index 1 and 2, unset index 2 and use `array_values` to reindex the sub whole array, that's it

Answer (score 0):

Extract the key values of array. Concatenate the both values (period, 0) and overwrite the index[1] with that result. Finally use unset to remove the index[2]

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

for ($i=0; $i < count($keys) ; $i++) {

  $array[ $keys[$i] ][1] =
    $array[ $keys[$i] ][1] . $array[ $keys[$i] ][2];

    unset($array[ $keys[$i] ][2]);
}

print_r($array);
```